# Convert dictionary into tuples

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
myDict = {0:{'value1':25,'value2':2500},1:{'value1':35,'value2':1000}}
```

Which I would like converted into tuples looking like this:

```
((25,2500),(35,1000))
```

By using the below code create a one-dimensional tuple for the 0 key. However I would like to create a multi-dimensional tuple.

```
tup = tuple(myDict[0].values())
```

Comment: `tuple(x.values() for x in myDict.values())` ? And if you really need `tuple` of `tuples`, `tuple(tuple(x.values()) for x in myDict.values())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do it by simple loop:

```
tuple(tuple(x.values()) for x in myDict.values())
```

if you need to sort result by dict key you can do it using `sorted`

```
tuple(tuple(v.values()) for k, v in sorted(myDict.items()))
```

Comment: That won't necessarily output the dict values in the same order, though. If you're unlucky you might get `((25,2500),(1000,35))`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey unless OP is using an OrderedDict there is no way around this. OP needs to determine what his requirements are WRT order

Comment: @Gillespie Of course there's a way around it. You can generate a list of all existing keys (like `['value1', 'value2']`), and then use that to always output the values in that order.

Comment: @Aran-Fey added second solution with sort by dict key

Comment: @Aran-Fey Like I said, OP needs to determine what his requirements are. Maybe he is feeding the tuples into some math functions that calculate averages in which case order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the `tuple`s in order,

```
>>> myDict
{0: {'value2': 2500, 'value1': 25}, 1: {'value2': 1000, 'value1': 35}}
>>> tuple((v['value1'], v['value2']) for k,v in sorted(myDict.items()))
((25, 2500), (35, 1000))
#   # order based on keyfunc ?
>>> tuple((v['value1'], v['value2']) for k,v in sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['value1']))
((25, 2500), (35, 1000))
```